# Blocking hostname if same as IP in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-dns

I've been noticing in my log files that sometimes the Hostname will be exactly the same as the Ip. I guessing that it's because there is no rDNS set. That being said, how can I block this in htaccess?

```
5/17/2014 01:44 PM | UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/29.0 | IP: 50.58.251.66
HOST: 50.58.251.66 | REFERRER: (empty) | TOR: False | GET DATA: [] | POST DATA: []
```

My htaccess line.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^%{REMOTE_ADDR} [NC,OR]
```

I've tested this and it does not seem to work. Seemed logical to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ would you want to block such requests?

Comment: I have an automated bad bot looking at my adwords listings and some of them are coming from bots that have this footprint

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to block these requests:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}::%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.+?)::\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: This seems to be catching ALL hosts that contain an IP address.

Comment: It does what your title says i.e. `Blocking hostname if same as IP in .htaccess`. If this is not what you want then clarify your question.

Comment: My apologies, I thought I had clarified that in the contents. How can I block only if the Ip is the exact same as the hostname ( see log file above)

Comment: But every time you access your website by `http://xx.yy.zz.nn/` host_name is same as IP address.

Comment: Not exactly. when I access a site or normal users do the come in like this `IP: 96.41.147.189 HOST: 96-41-147-189.dhcp.mdfd.or.charter.com`                     not like                                                        `IP: 50.58.251.66
HOST: 50.58.251.66`

Comment: I need to block if the IP is exactly the same as hostname, not just contains the IP

Comment: Well in that case above regex does exactly that. It will return 403 only for `if %{HTTP_HOST} == %{REMOTE_ADDR}`

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST} == %{REMOTE_ADDR}` this will match exactly the IP, not if it just contains it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54069/discussion-between-affiliatex-and-anubhava).

Comment: It will do exact match due to use of anchors `^` and `$`. You can do separate testing of this regex in an online tester. See this demo: http://regex101.com/r/oQ4iY8

Comment: Just tried it on live traffic and it's slipping through :(

Comment: Provide data rather then not so useful comments. What ip and what host name?

Comment: `5/20/2014 07:11 PM | UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36 | IP: 204.17.143.10
HOST: 204.17.143.10 |`